# UIApplication.shared.open is not working in ios 13

Tags: swift, openurl

I am trying to open google map, but the following code is not working in ios 13.

```
let addressForMap = address.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+", options: .literal, range: nil)
        if let url = URL(string: "comgooglemaps://?q=\(addressForMap)&center=\(lat),\(long)") {
          if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:],
              completionHandler: {
                (success) in
                 print("Open: \(success)")
             })
          } else {
            let success = UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            print("Open: \(success)")
          }
        }
```

In plist, I have added it:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>googlechromes</string>
    <string>comgooglemaps</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your url might be return nil, so they not open in browser or google map
 Please try url

```
if let url = URL(string: "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(latitude),\(longitude)&directionsmode=driving") {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
    }
```

Your try this url also

```
"https://maps.google.com/?q=@\(lat),\(lon)"
```

Comment: Yes, this url is working fine. But as we are only placing lat-long, in the url section location name is showing only lat, long not address, so my requirement is not filled up perfectly.

Comment: please try with the address in url.

Comment: can u send the address url?